# insights api action_breakdowns request param ignored

Tags: facebook-insights

v2.5

The following get request to the insights edge fails to yield the specified breakdown. The response yields the same number of rows regardless of whether the 'action_breakdowns' parameter is present or not. Here is the request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/act_nnnnnnnnnnnnnn/insights?level=adset&fields=adset_id,adset_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,impressions,inline_link_clicks,spend&time_increment=1&time_range[since]=2016-02-09&time_range[until]=2016-02-11&action_breakdowns=action_device&limit=25
```

Note that I have tried other formats for the action_breakdowns parameter, none of which work:

```
action_breakdowns[]=action_device
action_breakdowns=[action_device]
action_breakdowns={action_device}
```

Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong, or explain why the action_breakdowns parameter is seemingly ignored?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error experimentation I've found a way to breakdown adset level insight stats by device:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/act_nnnnnnnnnnnnnn/insights?level=adset&fields=adset_id,adset_name,campaign_id,campaign_name,impressions,inline_link_clicks,spend&time_increment=1&time_range[since]=2016-02-09&time_range[until]=2016-02-11&breakdowns=impression_device,placement&limit=25
```

Notice that **&action_breakdowns=action_device** has been replaced with **&breakdowns=impression_device,placement**. Also note that the reason 'placement' is included is that 'impression_device' cannot be used by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need call `action` in fields and only then use `action_breakdowns=`

example:

```
/insights?level=ad&fields=actions&action_breakdowns=action_device
```

pay attention! - **fields=actions** and **action_breakdowns=**  (**work only then you have fields=actions**)